# Python sorted() on list of numerical stings with leading zero not behaving as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I swear to the computer gods, previously I had a test involving the following built-in function sorting [ '002345', '98369'] to ['98369', '002345'] because lexicographically the zero should come last, right? But now a UnitTest that was previously functioning under that assumption is performing as pictured below.

```py
In[2]: x = ['98369', '002345']
In[3]: sorted(x)
Out[3]: ['002345', '98369']
```

So tell me, am I loosing my mind? There may have been a transition from python3.5 to 3.6, but I have documentation of successful unit testing after than transition.

-----EDIT-----

So I'm not losing my mind, I'm just a dummy.

I should have added that prior to asserting the results of the sorted list, I was casting the sorted list to a set. I know that negates the sort, so that is why I was getting variable results.

Comment: Zero is smaller than nine, so that's the reasoning for the sorting that way.

Comment: @mechanical_meat Well yes, if they were type int, but in this instance they are strings and should be sorted lexicographically. Or at least that was my understanding.

Comment: Symbol of zero comes before (smaller) than nine. It was always like so. See [AsciiTable](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: @gretchieem Try `'0' > '9'` in any Python shell. This hasn't changed with different Python versions.

Comment: So yes, I am loosing my mind. Thanks everyone. I just dont understand why this test wasnt failing until now. Concerning.

Comment: I realized I left out some important information. I was sorting prior to casting the list to a set. This is the source of variability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symbol of zero lexicographically comes before (smaller) than nine. It was always like so. See [AsciiTable](http://www.asciitable.com/).